# Add auto-scroll at bottom after the images previews are loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm facing a problem with an `auto-scroll` on the website I'm developing. The initial `auto-scroll` works properly but when loading the conversation, some messages contain images that are also loading. After being loaded the messages containing images get bigger, this sets wrongly the position of the scrollbar which is non longer at the bottom.

Do you know how to force the scrollbar to stay at the bottom until all images are loaded?

PS: I'm using Typescript / React for the frontend

Here is the function used to `auto-scroll` to the bottom (it is called each time the conversation is fetched/updated):

```
scrollToBottomChat(): void {
   const chatBody = document.getElementById("chatBody");
   if (chatBody) {
       chatBody.scrollTop = chatBody.scrollHeight;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow - Please provide a code sandbox or code snippets of how you are implementing auto scroll, image loading and scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React you shouldn't be using getElementById or any other direct DOM manipulations, it is considered an antipattern. Use ref instead
You should create a useEffect with a dependency ref's height, if it changes -> call scrollToBottomChat function.